# Get values from table columns and compare them

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, comparison

I am trying to compare values from a table and everything worked perfectly until I tried to compare a value with `0`.

```
var comparekeys;
comparekeys = function() {    
if ($("#keys tbody tr")) {
$("#keys tbody tr").each(function() {
  var a, b, row1, row2;
  a = $(this).find("td")[1].innerHTML;
  b = $(this).find("td")[2].innerHTML;
  row1 = $(this).find("td:eq(1)");
  row2 = $(this).find("td:eq(2)");
  if (a === 0) {
    if (b > 0) {
      $("<span class='dropped'> <b>Dropped</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxeq").css({
        'color': 'white',
        'float': 'right'
      }).appendTo(row1);
      return console.log("dropped");
    } else {
      $("<span class='notranking'> <b>Not Ranking</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxeq").css({
        'color': 'white',
        'float': 'right'
      }).appendTo(row2);
      return console.log("not ranking");
    }
  } else if (a !== 0) {
    if (a > b) {
      $("<span class='today'> <b>" + (a - b) + "</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxdown fa fa-arrow-down").css({
        'color': 'white',
        'float': 'right'
      }).appendTo(row1);
    } else if (a === b) {
      $("<span class='today'>  </span>").addClass("sortboxeq fa fa-bars").css({
        'color': 'white',
        'float': 'right'
      }).appendTo(row1);
      console.log("egal");
    } else {
      $("<span class='today'> <b>" + (b - a) + "</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxup fa fa-arrow-up").css({
        'color': 'white',
        'float': 'right'
      }).appendTo(row1);
    }
    if (a > b) {
      $("<span class='yesterday'> <b>" + (a - b) + "</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxup fa fa-arrow-up").css({
        'color': 'white',
        'float': 'right'
      }).appendTo(row2);
    } else if (a === b) {
      $("<span class='yesterday'>  </span>").addClass("sortboxeq fa fa-bars").css({
        'color': 'white',
        'float': 'right'
      }).appendTo(row2);
    } else {
      $("<span class='yesterday'> <b>" + (b - a) + "</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxdown fa fa-arrow-down").css({
        'color': 'white',
        'float': 'right'
      }).appendTo(row2);
    }
  }
});}};
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is this:
(if a = 0 and b > 0) => a dropped
(if a > 0 and b = 0) => b dropped
(if a > b) => a is up and b is down
(if a < b) => a is down and b is up
(if a = b)(while a = 0 and b = 0) => a and b not ranking
(if a = b)(while a > 0 and b > 0) => a and b are equal
Everything worked just fine until I have added the first two if statements, now the code just skips that part and goes to the other three where a is >, < or = to b
Any ideas what might cause the skip?

Comment: You're doing a strict comparison of `a` with `0`, so it's comparing the type. I'm guessing that `a` is a string, not an integer, in which case it wouldn't match

Comment: You are comparing 'a' wtih 0 by ===, but I think that type of 'a' is string, but 0 is integer, so it returns false, use just ==

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I solved it by changing a = $(this).find("td")[1].innerHTML; to a = Number($(this).find("td")[1].innerHTML)